# how to create a new model using Gazebo's xml language?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I following the tutorial http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=camera_save&cat=sensors to save images on the disk. But I do not know what code can I use to custom model or the world. For instance, 1. how to change the filename of saved images? 2. how to save only one latest image always. Because I do not want there are millions of images in my disk hours later. So I just want to save the one image per second and replace the old image instead of new image each second with the same filename.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17024/how-to-create-a-new-model-using-gazebo%27s-xml-language?/) by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As for the title, [this tutorial shows how to create a velodyne lidar](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i1). The xml format gazebo uses is called sdformat and the [specification is available here](http://sdformat.org/spec).

The name of the file comes from the name of the sensor. In the tutorial the images have the name `default_camera_link_my_camera`. `default` is because that's the name of the `<world>`. `camera` is the name of the `<model>` the sensor is on. `link` is the name of the `<link>` the sensor is on. `my_camera` is the name of the `<sensor>`. I don't think there is a way to tell gazebo to replace an old image with a new one without writing some code.

It can be done if you write a custom plugin to save the image. There are some general [tutorials about creating plugins here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=write_plugin). Once you're familiar with those I recommend using [the camera plugin source code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/2c58f1f337662a7ca4b85b5230b8c26a285f6682/plugins/CameraPlugin.hh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) as a starting point.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2017-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [langong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3715/langong/) on 2017-08-17**:
Good answers. Thank you very much!